# php, mysqli update with prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysqli

```php
function update_review($link, $user_id, $game_id, $rating, $title, $review) {
    $sql = "UPDATE reviews SET rating = ?, title = ?, review = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND game_id = ?";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    if ( !$stmt ) {
        die("could not prepare statement: " . $link->errno . ", error: " . $link->error);
    }

    $stmt->bind_param("sssii", $rating, $title, $review, $user_id, $game_id);
    if ( !$stmt ) {
        die("could not bind params: " . $stmt->error);
    }

    if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
        die("couldn't execute statement");
    }
}

function update_review2($link) {
    $sql = "update reviews set rating = \"43\", title = \"test\", review = \"blah\" where user_id = \"5\" and game_id = \"1\"";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    if ( !$stmt ) {
        die("could not prepare statement: " . $link->errno . ", error: " . $link->error);
    }

    if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
        die("couldn't execute statement");
    }

}
```

```php
var_dump($review_data);
// output = array(5) { ["user_id"]=> int(5) ["game_id"]=> int(1) ["rating"]=> string(2) "43" ["title"]=> string(4) "test" ["review"]=> string(4) "blah" }
update_review($link, $review_data['rating'], $review_data['title'], $review_data['review'], $review_data['user_id'], $review_data['game_id']);
```

Going to be honest, done the usual uni student thing and left the assignment to last min and regretting it again... 
Anyways been trying to figure this out for a few hours now and i've come to a loss, ive made it work by not using prepared statements as you can see above in the update_review2 function however when using the prepared statements version update_review it does not affect any rows in the db. If anyone can offer a bit of help it will be greatly appreciated especially because the deadline is in 6 hours!

Comment: WHERE are you updating the statement in update_review to?

Comment: Based on your above code the function call to update_review() has variables in one order while the function itself is declared in another order.

Comment: thank you so much @Ivan86 that was indeed the issue, something i must have looked over

Comment: Please read: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your above code the function call to update_review() has variables in one order while the function itself is declared with variables in another order.

Because of that, you might be passing a string when the statement is expecting an int.